# How to add components to TScrollBox dynamically one below another on button click?

Tags: delphi, tscrollbox

I have created one TScrollBox. I have added the Label and Edit Box on it dynamically on Button click. For setting the location of component i have used the height,width,left,top property of components. 
But when Scroll Bar gets appeared on screen after 5 components added, the next components location gets disturbed. and the next component is not placed in synchronous manner on ScrollBox.

Comment: There should be some property of the ScrollBox, like `ScrollTop` or `ScrollWhatever`. You can just subtract it from the new position of the component.

Comment: I am unable to find any property like ScrollTop.. :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `Top` coordinate for controls placed on a ScrollBox need to take into account the amount of "scroll" that already took place. If you add the controls all at once this is not a problem, because the ScrollBox doesn't get the chance to "scroll".

If you add controls to the ScrollBox *after* it got a chance to "scroll", you need to take into account the amount of vertical "scroll" that took place. Here's a sample piece of code that will add labels to `ScrollBox1`, taking vertical scroll into account so controls don't overlap each other. Here I'm using the form's "Tag" property to hold the `Top` for the next control added, and I'm also using `Tag` to generate unique names for the labels (so you can see they're going into the ScrollBox at the correct coordinates).

```
procedure TForm31.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var L: TLabel;
begin
  L := TLabel.Create(Self);
  L.Caption := 'Test: ' + IntToStr(Tag);
  L.Parent := ScrollBox1;
  L.Top := Tag + ScrollBox1.VertScrollBar.Size - ScrollBox1.VertScrollBar.Position;
  Tag := Tag + L.Height;
end;
```

An other approach I sometimes used is to keep track of the last control added and base the coordinates for the new control on the coordinates of that last added control:

```
var LastControl: TControl;

procedure TForm31.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var L: TLabel;
begin
  L := TLabel.Create(Self);
  L.Caption := 'Test: ' + IntToStr(Tag);
  L.Parent := ScrollBox1;
  if Assigned(LastControl) then
    L.Top := LastControl.Top + LastControl.Height
  else
    L.Top := 0;
  Tag := Tag + L.Height;

  LastControl := L;
end;
```

And yet an other approach would be to find the lowest control and add your control based on it's coordinates:

```
procedure TForm31.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var L: TLabel;
    Bottom, TestBottom: Integer;
    i: Integer;
begin
  // Find "Bottom"
  Bottom := 0;
  for i:=0 to ScrollBox1.ControlCount-1 do
    with ScrollBox1.Controls[i] do
    begin
      TestBottom := Top + Height;
      if TestBottom > Bottom then
        Bottom := TestBottom;
    end;
  L := TLabel.Create(Self);
  L.Caption := 'Test: ' + IntToStr(Tag);
  L.Parent := ScrollBox1;
  L.Top := Bottom;
  Tag := Tag + L.Height;
end;
```